# How to count wins within last 10 games for each player?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I want to pull the last 10 games for each player, and get how many wins they have.

These are my two tables:

player:

```
playerid | name
----------------
1        | Ben
2        | Sarah
3        | Jon
```

playergame:

```
playergamesid | playerid | win 
-------------------------------
1             | 1        | 0
2             | 3        | 1
3             | 1        | 0
4             | 2        | 1
5             | 3        | 0
6             | 1        | 1
7             | 1        | 1
8             | 2        | 0
9             | 2        | 1
10            | 3        | 0
etc.
```

The following SQL returns their total wins, however I only want to grab the most recent 10 games per player (I would need to sort playergameid by DESC to grab the most recent).

```
select 
player.name,
count(*) filter (WHERE playergame.win = 1) as won
from player
left join playergame on playergame.playerid = player.id 
group by player.name
ORDER BY won DESC
```

How could I amend my query to include a limit for each player? I imagine I would have to do it inside the filter but that doesn't look possible.

Comment: what if you add limit 10 to you query ?  working for you ?

Comment: Thing is, I want to limit it to 10 per a player, not overall.

Comment: i see , so you have to join your player table with a nested table that contains only last 10 games for every player from the table playergame

Comment: why not simply `sum(playergame.win) as won` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have last 10 games per player with row_number() ranking window funciton.
To get the win count for last 10 games per player:

```
with lasttengames as
(
select playergamesid , playerid , win ,row_number()over(partition by playerid order by playergamesid desc) rn from playergame
)

select 
player.name,
count(*) filter (WHERE playergame.win = 1) as won
from player
left join lasttengames on playergame.playerid = player.id 
where rn<=10
group by player.name
ORDER BY won DESC
```

Comment: You are most welcome @ditto. Best wishes.